# Create a thumbnail image every X seconds of the video

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, crop, video-processing

hello i have following command to get every second images from video.

```
  ffmpeg -i input.flv -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1 out%d.png
```

this command extract whole image every second . i want to get images from specific (x,y) position. for example i want to get images from top of left side of video.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1,crop=OUT_WIDTH:OUT_HEIGHT:X_POS:Y_POS out%d.png
```

- OUT_WIDTH/OUT_HEIGHT - the width/height of the output image
- X_POS/Y_POS - the top left corner of the output rectangle